# Cambiar un enlace generado por php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

En la plantilla Kalium de themeforest en la pagina que muestra los porfolios de las distintas galerías se genera un enlace con el texto "All" que muestra todos los elementos de todas las galerías, llevo varios días buscando donde cambiar ese "All" por "Todos" y no encuentro por ninguna parte donde se genera ese enlace. ¿Podría alguien echarme una mano?

[image: Pantallazo del inspector de chrome]

Comment: Algunas de esas plantillas (no se si es el caso) suelen tener disponible la posibilidad de traducir los contenidos estáticos (como esos enlaces) a través de archivos `.po`/`.mo`. Lo ideal sería que le consultes al diseñador de la plantilla.

Comment: Donde estan esos archivos .po / .mo ? (por cierto, gracias por el comentario)

Comment: He revisado algunas plantillas, otras usan archivos `.pot` (tienen la misma estructura) y suelen estar dentro del template en carpetas llamadas `lang` o `languages`. Pero están disponibles solo si el diseñador ha creado este método de traducción.

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿es un thema para Wordpress?  en ese caso instala el plugin "loco translate" mediante el cual puedes gestional los ficheros de traducción de una forma cómoda, te bastará con acceder a la traducción del tema, buscar la palabra "all" y asignarle una traducción.

Comment: Lo he intentado con el plugin y cambiando directamente el archivo .pot almacenado en la carpeta de traducción del theme, y no funciona.

Comment: Pueba a modificarlo en el archivo .po

Comment: Puede que por medio del .htaccess estén redirigiendo la url, prueba a mirar allí. Me lo he encontrado alguna vez.

Comment: También es posible que tengas que editar en el menú de la plantilla el idioma por defecto. O bien por un desplegable, o en un `input` con el código `es_ES`. Son las opciones similares que he encontrado editando plantillas de `WP`. Depende mucho del planteamiento del desarrollador.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo he solucionado , abriendo el proyecto en el editor Netbeans y buscando esa palabra en todas las carpetas con las opciones que brinda este editor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]